# Generate a single .py file from a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

let's say I have a module name `foo` which has around only 6-7 files I want to generate a single python file for that module.

like:

**main.py**

```py
from bar import kk

print(kk().hi())
```

**my bar.py**

```py
import time
from mm import hh

class kk:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "StackOverflow"

    def hi(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        print(hh)
        return self.name
```

my **mm.py**

```py
import random

def hh():
    return random.randint(0, 100)
```

so, i want my final **output file** as:

```py
import time
import random

def hh():
    return random.randint(0, 100)

class kk:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "StackOverflow"

    def hi(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        return self.name

print(kk().hi())
```

Answer (score 0):

'stickytape' looks like a package that does exactly what you want, it 'Converts Python packages into a single script':

https://pypi.org/project/stickytape/

(I have no experience with this package)

Comment: I have tried it already but it is doesn't merging all files function in one...

Comment: can you update your post and tell us what you tried and why it didn't work? And I'm curious why you want this?
there is also [pinliner](https://pypi.org/project/pinliner/), but it's not updated recently.
You can also write your own script that copies the content of all the files into a new file.